# Route Parameter Validation with Date Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am getting the validation failure message (status code 400) for all inputs, when i change the date format to string, the regex works but DateType validation not working. It accepts 2019-02-31 as a valid input. Any idea how to make it work DateTime parameter type?

```
    [HttpGet("{date}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get( [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$"), DataType(DataType.Date)] DateTime date)
    {
         return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Route Validation, you should avoid be used for `input validation`.

> Don't use constraints for input validation. If constraints are used
>   for input validation, invalid input results in a 404 - Not Found
>   response instead of a 400 - Bad Request with an appropriate error
>   message. Route constraints are used to disambiguate similar routes,
>   not to validate the inputs for a particular route.

Reference: [Route constraint reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#route-constraint-reference)

If you want to check the input by Route constraint, you could implement your own constraint by implementing `IRouteConstraint`.

1. `DateRouteConstraint`

   ```
   public class DateRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
   {
       public static string DateRouteConstraintName = "DateRouteConstraint";
       public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
       {
           object dateValue;
           if (values.TryGetValue("date", out dateValue))
           {
               DateTime date;
               string[] formats = { "yyyy-MM-dd" };
               if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue.ToString(), formats,
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
               {

                   return true;
               }
           }
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register `DateRouteConstraint`

   ```
   services.AddRouting(options =>
   {
       options.ConstraintMap.Add(DateRouteConstraint.DateRouteConstraintName, typeof(DateRouteConstraint));
   });
   ```
3. Use Case

   ```
   [HttpGet("{date:DateRouteConstraint}")]
   public ActionResult<string> Get(DateTime date)
   {
       return Ok();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply a `RegularExpression` attribute to a `DateTime` as it's not a string; that attribute is only valid for strings.

You *can* use a regex route constraint, i.e. `[HttpGet("{date:regex(...)}")]`, but in that scenario, you'd be better off using the `datetime` constraint instead: `[HttpGet("{date:datetime}")]`.

Comment: it works partially but treating this as valid date "02-25-201". I want to enforce a date format YYYY-MM-DD. Any idea how would enforce a date format in the route constraints?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing#get-books-by-publication-date

With dotnet core 3 i had to escape { and } (make them double) and it simply works :

```
[HttpGet("{date:datetime:regex(\\d{{4}}-\\d{{2}}-\\d{{2}})}")]
public WeatherForecast GetForecast(DateTime date)
...
```